# Java: How to get the last word of the dynamic string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have below string which I need to capture last word.

Below is my code but its not getting the last word.

The string at below location is dynamic and is not static string.

```
String secques1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-12 medium-4 medium-offset-4 columns']/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/label")).getText();

String lastWord = secques1.substring(secques1.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);`
```

Comment: It depends on your definition of a "word". You seem to specify "Anything that isn't a space".

Comment: you should add sample of the text you want to parse. Also, print what you get from secques1

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion string may contains space in it's trailing:

First: try to trim string trailing (string.trim())

second: print the whole text

and check the leading and trailing spaces then print the last word
I think this will help you.

Comment: bingo! worked thank you very much. I didn't use trim() and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The result of getText() is always with  blank.
And you made a mistake that if the secques1 end with bank the program will throw exception.
so ,you need to do like this:

```
String secques1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-12 medium-4 medium-offset-4 columns']/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/label")).getText().trim();
```

**add trim()**

```
String lastWord = secques1.substring(secques1.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String secques1 = " " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-12 medium-4 medium-offset-4 columns']/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/label")).getText();
String lastWord = secques1.substring(secques1.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```